# Standalone application transactions

Tags: java, spring, swing, hibernate, transactions

I have a standalone application written in Java Swing against MySQL via Hibernate, with just one client connected to the database, using `HibernateUtils` provided by Netbeans example app skeleton. Basically committing each transaction explicitly.

Now I need more than one client connected to the same MySQL server instance and I don't know how to manage connections properly. I'm integrating Spring context and `entityManager` but without an application server ¿How can and have the connections to the database synchronized?

I am concerned about the visibility of entities by different threads, so always keep refreshed.
EDITED:
I've been reading about the patterns related to session managing. In my application i have implemented de transaction-per-operation antipattern, opening and closing the session inside every DAO operation calling 'HibernateUtil'.This ensure that the data is allways updated, but now that I need more users connected, i don't know if I must change to a client-server architecture, or move to a JPA managed session configuration, or maybe keep working whith this anti-pattern.

Comment: It's a common question. Be more specific. What have you tried? Any problems?

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, I'm refactoring the Data layer with 'Don't repeat DAO' pattern, and trying to delegate commits to jta transaction, but i'd like to be sure that this is what I need to keep the threads synchronized, that connect via spring/jdbc to the same DDBB instance.

Comment: I'm reading similar questions and the problem is that this frameworks don't make it easy for distributed standalone applications without an application server supporting the database pool. The only 'easy' solution that I've found is to open and close the session everytime you work with the database.